# Team Foundation Server (TFS) - can't browse folders properly using Visual Studio

Tags: tfs

There seems to be a fault with my access to directories on Team Foundation Server.

See the image below.

I'm the only one with this problem. All of the other clients can connect to the server fine, so it must be my local copy of Team Foundation Server thats gone haywire.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Source control, documents and reports all exist in different systems with potentially different access rights - maybe your user account has broken permissions? Does a different account on the same machine still fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually a permissions problem.  Use the [TFSAdmin Tool](http://www.codeplex.com/TFSAdmin) to check permissions on the SSRS and Sharepoint systems (which are separate from TFS itself, unfortunately).  Check that the settings are working the way you intend by browsing directly to the Reporting website & the Team Project Portal from inside IE.

There are other possibilities, however.

- Check the Application event log on the server to see if your attempts to connect generate any exceptions.
- If you're using SQL Server 2008, make sure you have Team Explorer fully patched up to 2008 SP1.  (you'll need to re-run SP1 if you installed Team Explorer afterward)
- Make sure you're connecting to TFS using the same URI as other people.  If you're using a fully-qualified domain and they aren't (or vice versa) you could be exposing a server configuration problem in TFS's Registration database.  Details here: http://blogs.msdn.com/buckh/archive/2007/03/31/configuring-team-foundation-server-to-use-fully-qualified-domain-names.aspx  Also, there is a known bug in the admin util: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/959126
- Check, recheck, and re-recheck your proxy settings.  Both software configuration (TFS inherits them from IE / Control Panel) and at the network level (whether you're on some LAN segment that gets proxied differently).  Use an HTTP protocol analyzer on a good & bad machine to be certain.

Comment: Problem solved.

If I connect to it via the IP address of 192.168.1.40, it exhibits the symptoms explained above.

If I install Hamachi, and connect to it via a VPN tunnel, then it works fine. This is enough of a solution for me (same speed, different IP address).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after trying to connect to alternative address of our TFS server.
In my case it seemed that it just cached the previous TFS address although I changed it back to the original address.
What fixed it for me was to delete this folder:

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation
```